# How do I change the interface language of gitg in Windows?

Tags: gitg

I just installed gitg from the [Windows binaries](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/gitg/) on a Windows 7 machine. Even though the machine's display language is set to English, the interface for gitg displays in German locale. I've looked in settings (Einstellungen) but there doesn't seem to be a particular setting related to language.

My guess is that it's taking the locale from Windows' Region & Language > Location > Current Location, which is indeed set to Germany. If that's the case, I would consider this a bug as this is the wrong setting to determine an app's locale (display language would be the correct setting, imo).

Does anyone know where I could fiddle with the app's internal configuration so that I can force it to display in English?

Thanks!

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: Nope. Ended up uninstalling gitg in my Windows machine...

Comment: what did you use, afterwards?

Comment: GitExt  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

Not the best solution, but works for me: delete /rename the folder `gitg\share\locale\de`.

Comment: in my case, in archlinux, the file removed/renamed is `/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/gitg.mo`